# BS4 elements missing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse some HTML but the section that I want simply does not show up in the soup. Both the prior section and the posterior section are there, but not the one I want. Am I doing something wrong?

URL: https://coronavirus-portugal-esriportugal.hub.arcgis.com/
My code (with the URL):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://coronavirus-portugal-esriportugal.hub.arcgis.com/'
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
body = soup.body
print(body.prettify())
```

I am looking for the first four numbers (those corresponding to "Casos Confirmados", "Casos Suspeitos", "Recuperados", "Óbitos")

Comment: What is your want? Just body part?

Comment: I want the number under "Casos Confirmados" (currently 15987), which corresponds to <div id="ember57" (...) I just can't find it in the body soup (or in the soup) where it should be

Comment: The numbers aren't in the HTML, they're added using JavaScript. You need to use Selenium WebDriver to emulate it.

Comment: OK, thank you. Can you just confirm that that is also the case here: https://covid19.min-saude.pt/ponto-de-situacao-atual-em-portugal/  ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is retrieved dynamically from a backend SQL database. If you inspect the network traffic updating the page (and know a little SQL) you can work out how to write a query to send yourself to retrieve the portugal specific data. Here, 215 corresponds with Portugal.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/ncov_cases/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&where=OBJECTID=215&outFields=*')
print(r.json())
```

---

All data (use a different query):

```
https://services1.arcgis.com/0MSEUqKaxRlEPj5g/arcgis/rest/services/ncov_cases/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&where=1=1&outFields=*
```

---

You can also dynamically pick up the other identifier used in the query string

```
import requests, re

country_id = 215

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://coronavirus-portugal-esriportugal.hub.arcgis.com/')
    p = re.compile(r'https://services1.arcgis.com/(.*?)/arcgis')
    code = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    r = s.get(f'https://services1.arcgis.com/{code}/arcgis/rest/services/ncov_cases/FeatureServer/1/query?f=json&where=OBJECTID={country_id}&outFields=*')
    print(r.json())
```